# ¿Como puedo cerrar las etiquetas en Visual Studio Code, no encuentro la manera

Tags: vscode

En Visual Studio Code quiero poder cerrar las tags o etiquetas con algun comando, saben la manera no he encontrado la solucion o con que atajo se puede hacer, gracias !

Answer (score 2):

Podés hacerlo escribiendo el nombre de la etiqueta, sin los *símbolos* de menor y mayor encerrándola, por ejemplo "h1", y presionar la tecla *Tab*. Eso automáticamente te crea la etiqueta de apertura y de cierre.
Lo mismo si querés poner una etiqueta con un atributo, escribís "div.boton" y automáticamente se genera `<div class="boton"></div>`.

Comment: Muchas gracias srita. me ha salvado la vida, saludos desde México y gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: El cierre de etiquetas no funcionaban algunas veces por lo que descargué 'Auto Close Tags' de el menú de extensiones presionando [ctrl+shift+x]

Answer (score 0):

Un buen atajo es tocando las iniciales de la etiqueta que querés usar, por ejemplo **"li"** y luego tocas la letra **"tab"** automáticamente se abre y cierra la etiqueta y vos solo debes escribir tu código en el medio